# one if these permissions is required discord py

Tags: discord.py

I want the bot to check if the command auther has the check or the permission
@commands.check(mefle7)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)`

Example:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount):
      await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```